# Is there a way to "program" an extra display?

Tags: c#, windows-8

Is there a way to emulate/simulate a display in code, so that windows recognizes it as an extra screen? Kind of how you can render something to an off-screen render target, but make it an off-screen display device for windows to use.

Preferrably it should render to an off-screen RT, which I could then stream to my application on my tablet, and have my application there stream back touch-input to be used by windows.

This would really just act like a remote-admin-tool, but the remote client would have its own screen, as opposed to having control over one of the existing screens (or the desktop being locked, as remote desktop does).

Comment: sounds kind of like terminal services, though that's more for multi-users-each-with-their-own-display. This kind of tech would allow for the Avatar/Minority Report-type "screen fling", though...

Comment: My idea is to run the tablet as the primary display on my desktop computer, so that I can use the start-screen on it. And if it would perform well enough for running some metro-apps, I would not complain :P

Edit; And yes, that would be a cool use for it xD

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: it is somewhat possible when you make display drivers and let Windows think they are attached, but this goes beyond C#.

Comment: @jerone Well, I know c++ too, if I have to... But if it would involve changing the drivers for my graphics device, I think I'll be out in high waters :P

There "should" be a way, as windows really does this when you use remote desktop, though? Or have I misunderstood how that works?

Comment: Of course, RD doesn't lock the desktop when running on Server SKUs - which would tend to suggest that it may be possible but that you'll run afoul of licensing issues.